# Can't get Mule Studio Salesforce connector to connect, verified SF login and Security Token

Tags: login-errors, security-token, connect-api

I created a new demo project, from their canned demos, which only has 3 components.  I filled in my force.com developer login.  But any time I touch the SF icon in the diagram, or try to change any settings, I get:

"Getting DataSense metadata types failed: Invalid usernane, password, security token; or user locked out"

What I did:

- Fresh install of MuleSoft's Mule Studio.
- Software updates
- Verified login on Force web site
- Verified App login with "Force.com Explorer" (username, password, security token)
- Even tried changing security token and password and re-verified.
- For mulesoft Salesforce connector properties, I originally just updated 3 fields on the Connections tab: Username, Password, Security Token.
- Later I also tried updating the URL field to https://test.salesforce.com
- Not using any proxy info.
- I also waited over the weekend, in case my failed attempts had caused a lockout timer, but same thing this morning.

Again, I'm trying to do the simplest thing possible: Start with fresh install, new template project, fill in my credentials, and boom!

I'm guessing there's some other property that I need to set, but relatively new to both Mule and Force, so really don't know what else to check.

Comment: Are you seeing login attempts on the Manage Users -> Login History page?

Comment: I also tried starting from scratch with this video, http://youtu.be/UxnM4yQNiDU?t=1m50s, but it fails the same way when I click OK.  My dialogs don't look exactly like the video.  The Wizard pre-populates a URL of https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/28.0 but I'm not sure if that's right for "sandbox" access.

Comment: Weird, although I didn't get the template project running, I was able to get a bit further in this video: youtu.be/UxnM4yQNiDU but the trick is to NOT use the variable names, but instead use hard-coded values in that dialog box.  Strange stuff, and odd that the canned demo that's built-in doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the the 6.0 connector, the problem is your studio + ESB version.

I was having the same with the Studio of October and ESB v.3.5.2.

Solution:
- Studio 5.0.1
- ESB 3.6 EE